# What can be alternate way to load strip out javascript and put it in array for later use

Tags: php, javascript, regex, dom

I am using following code to strip out javascript from html dom string and put them in array for later use.

What can be alternate good use.

My Problem: 
I am getting problem with unicode inside the file. When files with unicode are parsed then it generates following error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() [domdocument.savehtml]: output
>   conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x97 0xC3 0xA0 0xC2 in

my code:

```
function loadJSCodeToLast( $strDOM ){
    //Find all the <script></script> code and add to $objApp
    global $objApp;
    $objDOM = new DOMDocument();
    //$x = new DOMImplementation();
    //$doc = $x->createDocument(NULL,"rootElementName");

    //$strDOM = '<kool>'.$strDOM.'</kool>';
    $objDOM->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    //$objDOM->formatOutput = true; 
    @$objDOM->loadHtml( $strDOM );
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($objDOM);

    $objScripts = $xpath->query('//script');
    $totCount = $objScripts->length;
    if ($totCount > 0) {
         //document contains script tags
        foreach($objScripts as $entries){
            $strSrc = $entries->getAttribute('src');
            if( $strSrc !== ''){
                $objApp->AddJSFile( $strSrc );
            }else{
                $objApp->AddJSScript( $entries->nodeValue );                    
            }
            $entries->parentNode->removeChild( $entries );
        }
    }
    //return $objDOM->saveHTML();
    //echo $GLOBALS['strTemplateDirAbs'];
    return preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $objDOM->saveHTML()));
}
```

Comment: What problem, specifically? Also, you can use `$objDOM->saveHTML($objDOM->documentElement)` instead of the messy stripping if you have PHP 5.3.6 or later.

Comment: updated the question with some more specific def

Answer (score 1):

Try converting your string with `utf8_encode()` before loading it.

```
$txt = utf8_encode($txt);

var_dump(loadJSCodeToLast($txt));
```

> The XML parser converts the text of an XML document into UTF-8, even
>   if you have set the character encoding of the XML, for example as a
>   second parameter of the DOMDocument constructor. After parsing the XML
>   with the load() command all its texts have been converted to UTF-8.
>
> In case you append text nodes with special characters (e. g. Umlaut)
>   to your XML document you should therefore use utf8_encode() with your
>   text to convert it into UTF-8 before you append the text to the
>   document. Otherwise you will get an error message like "output
>   conversion failed due to conv error" at the save()

From [DOMDocument::save documentation comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php#67952).